# Why does testing an app on an iPhone in Xcode 5/iOS 7 crash with calls to NSLog?

Tags: iphone, debugging, testing, ios7, xcode5

I've completed adapting my app for iOS 7 in Xcode 5, and it has tested fine in the simulator (for both iOS 7 and 6.1).  Before deploying for testing, I've run it a few times on my iPhone from Xcode 5, but the app frequently crashes with the error message:

> error: failed to launch 'app name/path' -- failed to get the task for process ####

I narrowed this down to NSLog calls.  This never happened before using the iOS 6 SDK.  Anyone know why this is the case?  Is it not good practice to have a few NSLogs in an app (even for reporting errors/warnings to the user's console)?

Comment: We use NSLog all over (via DLog) and it works fine in Xcode 5.

Answer (score 0):

Calling NSLog should not be a problem.

Cleaning Derived Data and changing my provisioning profile has helped for me.

Try to see this thread: [Xcode 5: failed to get the task for process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913676/xcode-5-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process)